# ShareLatex - Image Placement Question - APA

Tags: graphics, apa6

I'm hoping someone out there can help me.  I am trying to create a paper in ShareLatex using the APA format.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want my images to be within the text of the paper most of the time, and because of this, I use the floatsintext parameter in the documentclass. This seems to work well.  However, there are times where I would like to be able to have the image placed at the end of the paper as an appendix, which is the default APA style, but when I use floatsintext, it overrides the default.  Is there a command to say "don't use floatsintext, instead use the default of the template for this one instance?"

I thought perhaps if I got rid of the floatsintext, and then used an [H] for the image placement I could override the default APA and get the image to go where I put it in the paper, but no such luck.

HELP!  There has to be a way.  I would have thought I could get rid of floatsintext, and somehow there was a parameter with the includegraphics command that says "ignore the APA style default this time, and just put the image RIGHT HERE" - but if that exists, I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is a URL of a sample.

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59bfc60fe8f233253df3b23b

Ideally, I'd like the elephant to be inline with the text (as it is), and the puppy to be at the end of the paper (APA default).  Thank you for your help!

Corinne

Comment: `\includegraphics` does not need any such option as the graphic never moves it is just positioned the same way as a letter such as `x`.  Presumably you have graphic in a figure environment. The only purpose of `figure` is to move its content. So just `\includegraphics` the elephant and put the puppy in a `figure` environment.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you, David!  So here's a follow-up then.  If you follow the above link I made the change per your recommendations.  If I want a caption/label for the graphic, is there a way to make that happen?  I see that the \caption doesn't work for the \includegraphics, but I would like some way to label my graphic for the reader.

Comment: With `includegraphics` outside a `figure` environment you can use a `\captionof{figure}{your caption}` command from `caption` (or just `capt-of`) package. (see your example on Sharelatex)

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion in the comment is kind of a hack.

I would rather put the additional figures in an appendix and use floatsintext in the options as you suggested yourself:

```
\documentclass[floatsintext,man,apacite]{apa6}
% the other stuff
% first figure, will be in text because of floatsintext
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5in]{elephant.png}
\caption{Jumbo}
\end{figure}
% more stuff
\bibliography{sample}
% after bibliography, we set up an appendix
\appendix
% first appendix by using \section
\section{Additional figures}
% second figure
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5in]{puppy.png}
\caption{Puppy}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the complete version: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59d5067c8e70fc7b98c76e1d